# stem plot in javascript

Tags: javascript, stem-plot

I want to know how I can have something similar to the stem plot in Python.
Here is the definition:

`A Stem plot plots vertical lines at each x position covered under the graph from the baseline to y, and places a marker there.`

And photo example:

[image]

I searched on the internet and found nothing similar to this in javascript.
Is there a way to create such a chart in javascript?

Comment: am not really sure if they have it, but you should check out chart.js(it is used for diagrams and such)

Comment: I looked but there is nothing similar to this topic. I thought maybe I can find something like this in other libraries that I don't familiar with them.